# How do I set the default system properties for SBT in Windows?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am running `sbt` version 0.12.4 from command line on Windows and by default I need to use several system properties each time I do it, for example:

```
C:\example>sbt -Dsbt.ivy.home=c:\dev\.ivy2 -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.mydomain.net -Dhttp.proxyPort=1234 -Dsbt.global.base=c:\dev\.sbt  -Dsbt.boot.directory=c:\dev\.sbt\boot sbt-version
```

How do I set those system properties to be the default ones?

The [Configuration section](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Launcher.html#configuration) of the documentation does not say anything about default sbt.boot.propeties.

Comment: So you can write sbtWindows.bat, copy to path (c:\windows) and call your command :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on Mac, but I just put whatever flags I want in the sbt shell script.
Not sure how the Windows runner looks like lately, but you could edit the batch file if it's a bat; or make a new batch file if it's using sbt.exe kind of wrapper.